# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not recognized when added to UIView's subviews

Tags: swift, uiview

I currently have a subclass of `UIView` which contains numerous `subviews`. I wish to add a `UISwipeGesture` to the subviews but unfortunately the swipe gesture is not recognized. I've set `userInteractionEnabled = true` and direction of the swipe gesture but nothing works.

```
public class CardStackView: UIView{

  public var dataSource = [UIImage]()
  private var swipeGuesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

  override public func layoutSubviews() {
    for img in dataSource{
      let view = AppView(image: img, frame: self.frame)
      self.addSubview(view)
    }
    animateSubview()
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
  }

  func animateSubview(){
    for (index, sView) in self.subviews.enumerate() {
     swipeGuesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeGuestureDidSwipeRight(_:)))
      swipeGuesture.direction  = .Right
      sView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGuesture)
      sView.userInteractionEnabled = true
      let move: CGFloat = CGFloat(-20 + index * 20)
      let opacity = Float(1 - 0.2 * CGFloat(index))
      sView.shadowOpacity(opacity).shadowOffset(CGSizeMake(20 - CGFloat(index) * 5, 20 - CGFloat(index) * 5)).shadowRadius(5).moveX(-move).moveY(-move).gravity().shadowColor(UIColor.grayColor()).duration(1)
        .completion({
        }).animate()
    }
  }

  func swipeGuestureDidSwipeRight(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Swiped right")
    let subview = self.subviews[0]
    subview.moveX(-60).duration(1).animate()
  }


}
```

**Example**

```
class ExampleController: UIViewController {

  var stackView: CardStackView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stackView = CardStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 80, width: 200, height: 200))
    stackView.dataSource = [UIImage(named: "2008")!, UIImage(named: "2008")!]
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourSubview)
```

try this code for all your subviews and if it doesn't work try this in your controller class for your `CardStackView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `setNeedsLayout` for `stackView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    stackView = CardStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 80, width: 200, height: 200))
    stackView.dataSource = [UIImage(named: "2008")!, UIImage(named: "2008")!]
    stackView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
  }
```